# E185004 When 10% Through Loading Deltas Dump File for SVN

Tags: svn, svnadmin, svn-administraton

I have a deltas (version 3) dump file, which is about 48GB in size.

I attempted the following on my machine

```
svnadmin create ./path/to/testRepo

svnadmin load ./path/to/testRepo < ./path/to/my.dump
```

The dump file that I'm working with runs fine with no warnings until 10% of the way through (revision 5670 of 53082) I encounter: svnadmin: E185004: Unexpected end of svndiff input.

I don't know how to bypass the error. Also, since the file is so large, I don't know how to safely edit or split the dump file to troubleshoot.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What `svnadmin` version do you run? Run `svnadmin --version` to find this out.

Comment: BTW, what do you mean by "version 3"? Did you generate the dump from SVN 1.3 format repository? Or did you use SVN 1.3 command line tools and `svnadmin` in particular?

Comment: You can always split the dump file on revision boundaries. You can use the --incremental for following dumps, so it records only the deltas

Comment: The svnadmin --version command outputs the following:
    svnadmin, version 1.9.3 (r1718519)
    compiled Mar 14 2016, 07:39:01 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

Comment: As for "version 3" it means that dump file is a deltas dump file.

Comment: I unfortunately don't have access to the original server anymore and am only left with my current dump file.

Comment: The dump file fails when it encounters a zip file, although I'm not sure if that's a coincidence.